# Extending Backbone Objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype, underscore.js, extending

I am in need of extending the major Backbone functions (View, Model, Router) with some own members. However, the following does not work properly:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.foo = ["bar"];
```

Admittedly, the expression

```
testView = new Backbone.view.extend({})
testView2 = new Backbone.view.extend({})
alert(testView.foo.length);
```

states 1 but setting

```
testView2.foo.push("blah");
```

also added the string to testView.foo since the reference is identical.

Anyone has a smart idea how to extend those objectsm anyway?

Thanks in advance :)

Leo

Comment: thank you,
your comment made me think about what i asked for... it's obviously  ridiculous :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would not extend the standard View, and instead would create your own base view type. You should avoid changing values on the Backbone prototypes.

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  foo: null,
  initialize: function(options){
    this.foo = ["bar"];

    Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});

var testView = new BaseView();
var testView2 = new BaseView();
console.log(testView.foo.length); // prints '1'
console.log(testView2.foo.length); // prints '1'    

testView2.foo.push("blah");

console.log(testView.foo.length); // prints '1'
console.log(testView2.foo.length); // prints '2'
```